# grave accent in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, semantics

I am new in Haskell programming. I am trying to understand syntax and semantics of this language. I am a bit curious about the semantics of grave accent .
Why does this code work when we use grave accent?

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool  
elem' a [] = False  
elem' a (x:xs)  
    | a == x    = True  
    | otherwise = a `elem'` xs {-grave accent used in this line -}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The backquotes are used to treat any binary function as an infix operator.

```
a `elem'` xs
```

is identical to

```
elem' a xs
```

It is the complement to the use of `(+)` to use a binary operator as a function:

```
(+) 3 5
```

is identical to

```
3 + 5
```

Comment: The reference for this is section 3.2 of the Haskell Report (both '98 and 2010): http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2  An operator is either an operator symbol, such as + or $$, or is an ordinary identifier enclosed in grave accents (backquotes), such as ` op `. For example, instead of writing the prefix application op x y, one can write the infix application x` op ` y. If no fixity declaration is given for ` op ` then it defaults to highest precedence and left associativity (see Section 4.4.2).